# How to import excel sheet data into my ios app

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I am new to ios development. I want to import data from excel sheet and display that data in my app. And also i want to insert data into that excel sheet. How it can be possible.If anyone knows please help me.

Answer (score 1):

**Excel -> iOS:** 
You can export data from Excel to XML, using MS Excel 2007 or later. Or you can export data using .NET. Then you can import XML to iOS app, using `KissXML`, `TBXML` or any other XML framework.

**iOS -> Excel:**
To put data into Excel from iOS app you should do the same, transfer data using XML. For example, you can create a server api, that takes XML and runs C# program to import data to Excel sheet. You will have to write a small C# program that reads XML and imports that data to Excel using .NET libraries for working with MS Office.

[Here](https://github.com/wzbozon/ExcelFiller) is my example, how to work with Excel using .NET.

**To display Excel sheets** in iOS you can simply use UIWebView using method:

```
- (void)loadData:(NSData *)data MIMEType:(NSString *)MIMEType textEncodingName:(NSString *)textEncodingName baseURL:(NSURL *)baseURL;
```